# Libgdx ball game

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm really new to Libgdx engine. I've been trying to make a ball move randomly and bounce of the edges. It took me two days and I couldn't do it. I only have the ball bouncing up and down. There is a lack of documentation for this engine, so it's difficult to learn it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think there is very good documentation for libgdx. Just google it.. http://steigert.blogspot.ie/2012/02/1-libgdx-tutorial-introduction.html is a good tutorial... It uses libgdx 0.9.2 which is a bit old but it will get you started

Answer (score 2):

Some pseudocode:

```
If ball.radius + ball.x >= srceen.width or ball.x - ball.radius <= 0
    ball.velocityx *= -1
```

Comment: Without knowing the layout of the rest of the code, the variable names, and so on, that would be almost impossible. Try and implement a system similar to above.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
    rev=-1;
    vy = intSpeedY;
    vx = intSpeedX;

    ball.x += vx;
    ball.y += vy;
    if (ball.x + ball.radius > right) {
      ball.x = right - ball.radius;
      vx *= rev;
    } else if (ball.x - ball.radius < left) {
      ball.x = left + ball.radius;
      vx *= rev;
    }
    if (ball.y + ball.radius > bottom) {
      ball.y = bottom - ball.radius;
      vy *= rev;
    } else if (ball.y - ball.radius < top) {
      ball.y = top + ball.radius;
      vy *= rev;
    }
```

good luck.